# NodeJS package to generate correlated data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data

I am looking to create a synthetic database and for that I need to generate some ordinal data that has a correlation, say 0.5.

I have seen packages in R to generate correlated ordinal data based on base probabilities and correlations.

Since I wanted to integrate the synthetic data with my backend in NodeJS, I am looking for such a package in NodeJS.